# Remove underline on span in anchor tag

Tags: html, css

I have an interesting problem I am trying to solve. I have an anchor element with some span text element inside

```css
.link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">Hi <span class="inside-text">there</span> dude.</a>
```

What I'm trying to remove the `underline` on the span `.inside-text` and just underline the text outside the `span` on hover. I tried this

```
.text-inside {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

but it doesn't seem to solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `display:inline-block` to span

```css
.link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.link:hover .inside-text{
  text-decoration: none;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">Hi <span class="inside-text">there</span> dude.</a>
```

Comment: in fact is enough with inline-block

Comment: @DanielAbril Yes